# Zero-knowledge proof with only a ciphertext

Tags: symmetric, zero-knowledge-proofs

Suppose there is a plaintext **p**, which is encrypted with a symmetric cipher using a key **k**, resulting in a ciphertext **c**. Bob knows both **c** and **k**, but Alice knows only **c**. Is there any protocol by which Alice can be certain (maybe with some probability) that Bob indeed does know **p**, without revealing to her **p** itself?

Also, it be great to not have to have any third-party involved.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but I found [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55721/can-we-prove-possession-of-an-aes-256-key-without-showing-it) which is somehow related (here Alice knows $p$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: every statement in NP can be proven in zero-knowledge, meaning, without revealing anything more than the very fact that the statement is true. In fact, this result can be extended to proofs of *knowledge*, where the prover does not only show that a statement is true, but also that he does know a witness (still without revealing it).

Of course, general techniques are very inefficient. For standard symmetric ciphers, the best approaches will use general zero-knowledge proofs for statements represented by boolean circuit - see my answer to the question that AleksanderRas links to in the comment section. You should also note that if you replace the symmetric cipher by a cipher with a strong algebraic structure, such as ElGamal, then much (much) more efficient solutions exist - for example, in ElGamal, proving knowledge of a plaintext requires only exchanging a few string (about twice more communication than simply sending the ciphertext - so really not much).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where the following statement: `every statement in NP can be proven in zero-knowledge` was proved?

Comment: yes, look up "proofs that yield nothing but their validity and a methodology of cryptographic protocol design". In modern terms, the underlying assumption is the existence of OWFs.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau: Is it possible to prove that $r_1 = r_2$ in the ElGamal ciphertext $(r_1G, xG + r_2H)$ without revealing either $xG$ or $r_2H$?

Comment: this is a trivial statement: any pair of group elements can be seen as an ElGamal encryption with r1 = r2, for *some* x. This is in fact equivalent to saying that any pair of group element is a valid Elgamal ciphertext.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau: what if the $x$ has to be greater than $0$? If you do a range-proof (e.g. Bulletproofs) on $xG + r_2H$, then, if $r_1 \neq r_2$, the decrypted $x$ will be different and can be $<0$, right? Can you do the range-proof on $xG + r_2H + r_1G$ instead to solve this?

Comment: greater than 0 is not obvious to define over known order groups, but if by that you mean that the natural mapping of $x \in G$ to map$(x) \in [-p/2,p/2]$, then sure, this becomes a well defined NP language L and - as for any NP language - you can prove in zero-knowledge that a word belongs to L (e.g. using a range proof as you suggest).